# Accordion inside a Tabbed Navigation

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am creating a simple page with a number of tabs, and inside each tab there will be 3 sections which I am using an accordion for as this is the best solution for what I want. Everything works perfectly on the first tab, the accordion operates as it should and the content is rendered fine.

When I click on tab2 the content is rendered as just text with no accordion applied. I have used the dev tools and the accordion class is not being applied to the accordion div in tab2 for some reason. It may be that I am missing something really fundamental here but I would appreciate any help.

Excuse the basic code layout here but for demonstration purpose this is what the html might look like.

```
<body>
<h1 class="mainTitle">Page Title</h1>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1"><!-- Start of tabs-1 -->
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
        This section is for general information relating to this project.
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 1 content
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 2 content
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of accordion -->
</div><!-- End of tabs-1 -->

<div id="tabs-2"><!-- Start of tabs-2 -->
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
        This section is for general information relating to this project.
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 1 content
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 2 content
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of accordion -->
</div><!-- End of tabs-2 -->
</div><!-- End of tabs -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple divs with the same id, namely accordion. Either name them seperately, or use a class with your selector. For example:

```
<body>
<h1 class="mainTitle">Page Title</h1>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
   <div class="accordion">
       <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
        This section is for general information relating to this project.
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 1 content
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 2 content
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of accordion -->
</div><!-- End of tabs-1 -->

<div id="tabs-2"><!-- Start of tabs-2 -->
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
        This section is for general information relating to this project.
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 1 content
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        Section 2 content
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of accordion -->
</div><!-- End of tabs-2 -->
</div><!-- End of tabs -->
</body>
```

And then:

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew it would be something basic like that,not sure how I missed it, must be out of practice.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `<div>`s with the same ID ("accordion").  I would recommend changing them to use a class of "accordion" rather than an ID, then change your jQuery to apply the accordion effect to `<div.accordion>`.